# Configure pyproject.toml for unittest and coverage

Tags: python, python-unittest, coverage.py

I used in the pass `pytest` but wanted to use this time `unittest` instead. I use the integrated testframework from vscode and for testing it just runs fine. Further I wanted to use `coverage`. My structure is as usual:

```
┣ mypackage
┃  ┣ subpackage
┃  ┃  ┗ mymodule.py
┃  ┣ __init__.py
┃  ┗ main.py
┣ tests
┃  ┗ test_mymodule.py
┗ pyproject.toml
```

I've included the following to my `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.coverage.report]
fail_under = 80

[tool.coverage.run]
branch = true
include = ["mypackage/*"]
command_line = "-m unittest discover -s tests/"
```

If I now run `coverage run` it outputs

```bash
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

And if I run coverage report:

```bash
Name                               Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover
--------------------------------------------------------------------
mypackage/__init__.py                  9      0      2      0   100%
mypackage/subpackage/mymodule.py      15      2      2      0    88%
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                 24      2      4      0    93%
```

But why is my `main.py` not included? It also includes code which is not tested yet and expected coverage to realize that. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should add this line to your file:

```
source = ["."]
```

That tells coverage to examine the whole tree for files to consider, even if they were never run.

Comment: had this in the `pyproject.toml` before and coverage only sees tested modules. Additionally also `tests/test_mymodule.py` joined report. I continued with testing and as soon as I test modules which import not tested modules/classes/functions are added to the report. Is this wanted behaviour and I just was confused in this early stage?